# Unable to retrieve returned object from an async function

Tags: javascript, twitter, async-await

I'm struggling to log a tweet function's response values to the console but no matter what I do, the object keeps returning empty even though the tweet gets posted.

```
const Twitter = require('twitter');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY_TEST,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET_TEST,
  access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY_TEST,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_TEST
});

const tweet = (message, id = '0') => {
  let postRes = {};
  let status = {};
  if(id && id.length > 4) {
    status = {
      in_reply_to_status_id: id,
      status: message,
    };
  } else {
    status = {
      status: message,
    };
  }
  client.post('statuses/update', status)
  .then((tweet, response) => {
    console.log('id', tweet.id); // Tweet body.
    console.log('id_str', tweet.id_str); // Tweet body.
    console.log('text', tweet.text); // Tweet body.
    postRes.tweet = tweet.text,
    postRes.id = tweet.id_str;
    return postRes;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('ERR');
    throw error;
  });
  // console.log('POSTRES', postRes);
  return postRes;
};

async function msg() {
  const tweeted = await tweet('this is_a__posts_async', '');
  console.log('TWEETED', tweeted);
  console.log('MESSAGE', tweeted.tweet);
  console.log('ID', tweeted.id);
}

msg();
```

Here, I expect the statement `console.log('TWEETED', tweeted);` to return an object with two elements, the tweeted text and the posted tweet's id. However, despite having it wrapped inside of an async function, it returns empty.

Comment: I didn't check it thoroughly, but shouldn't you await the call to msg() too? To me, it seems that this program finishes before the async msg() ends, although I don't recognize the language it is written in.

Comment: The code is in Javascript. And `msg()` runs alright because the tweet does get posted.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know Javascript had async/await. A pity it didn't help, but since I wasn't sure, I put it as a comment rather than as an answer.

Comment: You need to `return` the promise that your `then()` creates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, i think you are on the right track here, but you need to resolve the promise when the call returns successfully, like so:

```
const Twitter = require('twitter');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY_TEST,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET_TEST,
  access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY_TEST,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_TEST
});

const tweet = (message, id = '0') => {
  // no direct return value
  let status = {};
  if(id && id.length > 4) {
    status = {
      in_reply_to_status_id: id,
      status: message,
    };
  } else {
    status = {
      status: message,
    };
  }
  return client.post('statuses/update', status)
  .then((tweet, response) => {
    console.log('id', tweet.id); // Tweet body.
    console.log('id_str', tweet.id_str); // Tweet body.
    console.log('text', tweet.text); // Tweet body.
    postRes.tweet = tweet.text,
    postRes.id = tweet.id_str;
    // here we resolve with the successful promise to keep the chain intact
    return Promise.resolve(postRes);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('ERR');
    throw error;
  });
};

async function msg() {
  // to handle any thrown errors use a try/catch here 
  try {
    const tweeted = await tweet('this is_a__posts_async', '');
    console.log('TWEETED', tweeted);
    console.log('MESSAGE', tweeted.tweet);
    console.log('ID', tweeted.id);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(`Error during post: ${error}`);
  }
}

msg();
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

Try turning your `tweet` function to `async` function as shown below or you could return the whole promise itself from the `tweet` function.

```
async function tweet(message, id = '0') {
  let postRes = {};
  let status = {};
  let tweet;
  if(id && id.length > 4) {
    status = {
      in_reply_to_status_id: id,
      status: message,
    };
  } else {
    status = {
      status: message,
    };
  }
  try{
   tweet = await client.post('statuses/update', status)
  }
  catch(error){
     console.log('ERR: ', error)
     throw error
   }
   console.log('id', tweet.id); // Tweet body.
   console.log('id_str', tweet.id_str); // Tweet body.
   console.log('text', tweet.text); // Tweet body.
   postRes.tweet = tweet.text,
   postRes.id = tweet.id_str;
   return postRes;

};

async function msg() {
  const tweeted = await tweet('this is_a__posts_async', '');
  console.log('TWEETED', tweeted);
  console.log('MESSAGE', tweeted.tweet);
  console.log('ID', tweeted.id);
}

msg();
```

Return the whole promise.

```
const Twitter = require('twitter');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY_TEST,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET_TEST,
  access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY_TEST,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_TEST
});

const tweet = (message, id = '0') => {
  let postRes = {};
  let status = {};
  if(id && id.length > 4) {
    status = {
      in_reply_to_status_id: id,
      status: message,
    };
  } else {
    status = {
      status: message,
    };
  }
  return client.post('statuses/update', status)
  .then((tweet, response) => {
    console.log('id', tweet.id); // Tweet body.
    console.log('id_str', tweet.id_str); // Tweet body.
    console.log('text', tweet.text); // Tweet body.
    postRes.tweet = tweet.text,
    postRes.id = tweet.id_str;
    return postRes;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('ERR');
    throw error;
  });
  // console.log('POSTRES', postRes);
  // return postRes;
};

async function msg() {
  const tweeted = await tweet('this is_a__posts_async', '');
  console.log('TWEETED', tweeted);
  console.log('MESSAGE', tweeted.tweet);
  console.log('ID', tweeted.id);
}

msg();
```

Thanks, Bergi for pointing out the scope issue.

Comment: Declaring `let tweet` inside the `try` body doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

> Async/await is Syntactic Sugar For Promises in ES8 Javascript but sometimes it becomes little overwhelming when you are resolving a promise. Recently, I immersed my whole day trying to get used to them.

**You have to wrapp every function in `async` that tries to utulise promised based function look at the code below to get used.**

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY_TEST,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET_TEST,
  access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY_TEST,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_TEST
});

const tweet = (message, id = '0') => {
  let postRes = {};
  let status = {};
  if(id && id.length > 4) {
    status = {
      in_reply_to_status_id: id,
      status: message,
    };
  } else {
    status = {
      status: message,
    };
  }
  client.post('statuses/update', status)
  .then((tweet, response) => {
    console.log('id', tweet.id); // Tweet body.
    console.log('id_str', tweet.id_str); // Tweet body.
    console.log('text', tweet.text); // Tweet body.
    postRes.tweet = tweet.text,
    postRes.id = tweet.id_str;
    return postRes;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('ERR');
    throw error;
  });
  // console.log('POSTRES', postRes);
  return postRes;
};

async function msg() {
  try{
     const tweeted = await tweet('this is_a__posts_async', '');
     console.log('TWEETED', tweeted);
     console.log('MESSAGE', tweeted.tweet);
     console.log('ID', tweeted.id);
     //it returns <Promise>
     return tweeted;
  }catch(error){
      console.log('Something went wrong', error);
      return;
  }

 } 
 //No need to call getTweeks
async function getTweets(){
  try{
    //Do what you want with this Object
   const tweet = await msg();
  }catch(error){
      console.log('Something went wrong', error);
      return;
  }
}
```

I guess this would help you.